# grep a pattern until a specific character (:)

Tags: regex, grep

Consider the following `file.txt`:

```
@A00940:70:HTCYYDRXX:2:2101:1561:1063 1:N:0:ATCACG
TAGCACTGGGCTGTGAGACTGTCGTGTGTGCTTTGGATCAAGCAAGATCGG
+
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:FFF::FFFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFFF
@A00940:70:HTCYYDRXX:2:2101:2175:1063 1:N:0:ATCACG
CGCCCCCTCCTCCGGTCGCCGCCGCGGTGTCCGCGCGTGGGTCCTGAGGGA
+
FFFF:FFFFF:FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
@A00940:70:HTCYYDRXX:2:2101:2772:1063 1:N:0:ATCACG
TGGTGGCAGGCACCTGTAATCCCAGCTACTCGGGAGCCTGAGGCAGGAGAA
```

I am trying to `grep` all the characters of the lines that start with `@` up to `:` but not including the colon, in this example the result would be `A00940`.

I have tried this:

`cat file.txt | grep '[^:]*'`

and this:

`cat file.txt | grep '^(.*?):'`

but both commands do not work, why is that?

Comment: I think you mean "not including the colon". There is no semicolon anywhere in the text.

Comment: yep I corrected. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pattern `[^:]*` matches 0+ times any character except `:` which does not take an `@` char into account. As the quantifier is `*` it can also match an empty string.

This pattern `^(.*?):` matches from the start of the string, as least as possible characters till the first occurrence of `:` and also does not take the `@` char into account.

---

One option is to use `-P` for a Perl compatible regex with a positive lookbehind to assert an `@` to the left.

```
grep -oP '(?<=@)[^@:]+' file.txt
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=@)` Positive lookbehind, assert from the current position an `@` directly to the left
- `[^@:]+` [Negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), match 1+ times any character except `@` and `:`

Output

```
A00940
A00940
A00940
```

Another option using gawk with a capture group:

```
gawk 'match($0, /@([^@:]+):/, a) {print a[1]}' file.txt
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use something simple like `@(\w+)`?

Comment: @JeffC Because that will keep the @ in the output.

Comment: Ah... can you not return groups using `grep`? I don't do `grep`... just wondering.

Comment: @Thefourthbird could you explain why my grep solution did not work ?

Comment: @Thefourthbird could you also explain how `(?<=@)` works ?

Comment: @alex I have added some details to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/@[^:]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)}' Input_file
```

With `sed` solution: Simply stop printing for all lines and print only those lines where match is found by regex.

```
sed -n 's/^@\([^:]*\):.*/\1/p' Input_file
```

Comment: could you explain how this part of sed `^@\([^:]*\):.*` command works ? i don't quite follow . thanks

Comment: @alex, sure, first stopping printing by -n option for all lines. Then checking if line starts from @ and creating a capturing group ([^:]*\) (to keep matched values into memory) later substituting whole line with \1 which means by 1st capturing group, p means print that, since we stopped printing for all lines in starting. Let me know please in case you have any queries here. Cheers

Comment: this part specially I don't get it,  `([^:]*)` matching group is `()` then class group `[^:]*` is this zero or more characters from class group that do not have a colon ?

Comment: @alex, yes please `[^:]` this means match till first occurrence comes of `:` after that `*` takes care of matching everything till `:` first occurrence comes.

Comment: wow ok I thought `[^:]` means negation i.e. any single character not in the list, from GNU regex https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html

Comment: @alex, `[^:]` this alone will not do the trick, `[^:]*` will do the trick actually. This will make sure to match everything till 1st occurrence of : comes :) cheers

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers, another way to get the output is with the following

```
awk -F '@|:' '$2=="A00940" {print $2}' file.txt
```

That sets the delimiter as either `@` or `:` and then prints the second column where the value is `A00940`:

Output:

```
A00940
A00940
A00940
```